# Woocommerce - manage stock on attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I don't know if this is possible, but here goes.

Let's say that I have some products that are based upon the customer picking 2 dates.

Part1, has 3 dates, and so does Part2. The customer cannot only pick a date from Part1 without also picking a date from Part2, and vice versa.

I therefore set up the product as variable, and i did it like this:

[image: Variable product]

With this approach I would have thought that I would be able to manage the stock of each attribute. But unfortunately not. When bought it will only deduct the stock of dates in Part 1 and not in Part2.

I therefore tried to set i up like this:

[image: Variable product 2]

Sort of works, but doesn't quite fit what I need, cause now the dates are sold as a set, and therefore also stock managed as a set.

Let's say that each date has an availability on 10 in stock and I have 10 customers. All 10 customers pick Date 1 form Part1, and then picks some random dates from Part2. Now Date 1 should be sold out. But that's not the case since I've actually created 3 sets that include date 1, and they all have the availability of 10.

Phew, I hope this makes any sense. Can this be done, or should I try a completely different approach? Your help is much appreciated!

If I need to use a plugin, it doesn't have to be free.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. It seems like what you need is a booking plugin, but really can't tell from what you've written. I think you need to do some heavy editing.

Comment: I'll look into editing the question. But disregard the "dates". The attributes could literally be anything. Look at it as a bundle. For example: The Main product consists of 2 mandatory sub-products that has sepperat inventory. But in Woocommerce I cannot create a "main" grouped/bundled product, when the 2 sub-products has variations. .

Comment: Also, the sub-products should not be able to be purchased individually

Comment: I agree totally with James Jones: **(Kindly) Your question is not understandable (very unclear and fuzzy) as it is**… One of my specialities as a woocommerce developer is deploying for clients extreme custom booking systems… But here is impossible to help/guide you for now. So you should rewrite completely your question (may be asking people around you before, to see if what you are asking is clear, detailed and enough illustrated). **Also you should begin your question explaining what is your shop and what the customers are going to buy.** Then you can expose what are your needs… etc…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using variations to manage stock so it seems clear that you might need this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-variable-stock-management/

This plugin will enable the management of stock to variation attributes.

Comment: The linked plugin is no longer maintained. You can use [Attribute Stock for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attribute-stock-for-woocommerce/) instead.